# Three Evil Shades

Tags: riddle, rhyme

A blind man was walking through a lush forest when he came upon three evil shades lurking in the shadows.  The shades spoke to the man:

> "Our first is regal and magical true,
>
> But also a sign that something hurt you,
>
> Our second rises with the sun,
>
> From atop a tree it's name did come,
>
> Our third is most prevalent here,
>
> All three are secondary, Dear.
>
> What are we?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Our first is regal and magical true,
But also a sign that something hurt you,

> Purple is often associated with with royals, due to the extreme value of purple dye in the past. <s>I'm not sure where danger comes into it (maybe specific drugs or danger on Baldwin County public beaches, guessing from a quick google search).</s> Bruises are often purple.

Our second rises with the sun,
From atop a tree it's name did come,

> The Sun often appears orange, as does the sky while it's rising; Oranges grow on trees.

Our third is most prevalent here,

> In a forest, most things are Green.

All three are secondary, Dear.

> The secondary colors are purple, green and orange.

Comment: Yep.  Well done.  +1

Comment: I assume "shades" is a play on "shades of colour"? Clever.